# Why my data is not showing in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, petapoco

I am using petapoco orm in mvc 4. when i going to show my total client list from database table it showing me object reference not set to and instance of a object. I have also some data or information in my Client Table. Why this error is showing , Please help me...
my index view is.

```
@model IEnumerable<FCBook.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Client list";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fax)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostalCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fax)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostalCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ClientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ClientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ClientId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Client/Create

        [Httppost]
        public ActionResult Create(Client collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                var db = new PetaPoco.Database("FCbook");
                if (collection != null)
                {
                    collection.Insert();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: where error is coming on view or in controller

Comment: Showing error in this line in index view @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: show the controller method for action `Index`

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new PetaPoco.Database("FCBook");
            var Cllist = db.Query<Client>("Select * from Client");
            if (Cllist != null)
            {
                return View(db);            
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("");
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller for your `Index` method

```
public ActionResult Index()
 { 
    var db = new PetaPoco.Database("FCBook"); 
    var Cllist = db.Query<Client>("Select * from Client"); 
    if (Cllist != null)
     { 
        //Convert your Cllist into list of your Model i.e List<FCBook.Client>
        return View(Cllist);
     }
   else
     {
       return RedirectToAction("");
     } 
}
```

Comment: YAH got it...boss it is working....

Answer (score 0):

Your view require a model `@model IEnumerable<FCBook.Client>`. But you didn't pass a model when calling `return View();` . I see that you'd like to display `Client` list via `GET` method.

Instead of

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

It should be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //connect to datasource and query for Client list
    model = ...

    return View(model);
}
```

See [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) for more detail on MVC4